# How to solve this integral using polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve the exercise 5 in the section 11.28 on page 399 in the [Apostol's calculus book vol 2](http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Apostol%20-%20CALCULUS%20-%20VOLUME%202%20-%20Multi%20Variable%20Calculus%20and%20Linear%20Algebra,%20with%20Applications%20to%20Differential%20Equations%20and%20Probability.pdf).

The exercise is to express the double integral $\iint_S f(x,y)dxdy$ as an iterated integral in polar coordinates.

The item I have troubles is the fifth one:

$S=\{(x,y);x^2\le y\le 1,-1\le x\le 1\}$

The solution given in the end of the book is:

[image]

I didn't understand why, I thought the solution should be the first integral above but with the limits $0\le \theta\le \pi$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drawing is correct.

When converting to polar coordinates, we have
$$
S = \{ (r, \theta) \mid 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi \text{, } h_1 (\theta) \leq r \leq h_2 (\theta) \} ,
$$
where $h_1(\theta) = 0$ for every $\theta \in [0, \pi]$, but where $h_2$ is piecewise-defined. We'll define $h_2$ below.

- For every $\theta$ in $[0,\pi/4]$, the point $(x,y)$ on the outer boundary of $S$ has polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ satisfying
  $$
  y = x^2 \quad \iff \quad r \sin \theta = r^2 \cos^2 \theta \quad \iff \quad r = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2 \theta} =  \tan \theta \sec \theta,
  $$
  so $h_2(\theta) = \tan \theta \sec \theta$.
- For every $\theta$ in $[\pi/4, 3 \pi/4]$, the point $(x,y)$ on the outer boundary of $S$ has polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ satisfying
  $$
  y = 1 \quad \iff \quad r \sin \theta = 1 \quad \iff \quad r = \dfrac{1}{\sin \theta} = \csc \theta,
  $$
  so $h_2(\theta) = \csc \theta$.
- For every $\theta$ in $[3 \pi/4, \pi]$, the point $(x,y)$ on the outer boundary of $S$ has polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ satisfying
  $$
  y = x^2 \quad \iff \quad r \sin \theta = r^2 \cos^2 \theta \quad \iff \quad r = \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2 \theta} =  \tan \theta \sec \theta,
  $$
  so $h_2(\theta) = \tan \theta \sec \theta$.

This gives the description of $S$, and therefore the three integrals.

Comment: How do you know the angles the functions are defined? why for example the first one is from $0$ to $\pi/4$? thank you for your answer.

Comment: Again, you are looking at the outer boundary of $S$ in the drawing. As $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi$, the boundary is given by $y=x^2$ from $\theta=0$ to $\theta = \pi/4$. But then things change: the outer boundary is no longer given by $y = x^2$ between $\pi/4$ and $3 \pi/4$; rather, it is given by $y=1$. Similarly for $\theta$ between $3 \pi/4$ and $\pi$. You have to get the polar equations of the outer boundary along the three subintervals $[0, \pi/4]$, $[\pi/4, 3 \pi/4]$, $[3 \pi/4, \pi]$ of the interval $[0, \pi]$.

Comment: And technically, we should be using a different symbol for the region $S$ after converting to polar coordinates. But forget that! :)